# Having Function Objects Auto Detect Type in c++

Tags: c++, templates, function-object

I wanted to sort a vector containing ints in reverse order, but since I had gotten so used to type deduction in c++ I had passed the function object **greater<>()** without specifying int, since what else could it be? This did not work using g++, but did work with the visual studio compiler, however I noticed that void was used by visual studio (not sure if this is ok). Is it possible for a function object to auto deduce types, why or why not? If not is there some workaround, as types can get long to type?

Comment: which version of g++ did you use? Did you specify `std=c++14` ?

Comment: No, it was c++11, it was 5.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that was introduced by c++14 (which is supported by g++5.1 and can be activated by passing the `-std=c++14` flag).

If you don't specify a type, the compiler takes the default one (`void`) for which there exists [a specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void). This specialization has a templated `operator()` member function for which the parameter types are then deduced by the compiler according to the iterator's value type.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specialization of [`std::greater<void>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), `void` being the default template argument of `std::greater<class T>` since C++14.

This specialization simply implements `x > y`, deducing argument and return types .